# Ruby on Rails - Why aren't all my course averages displaying?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Stuck student here - wondering if you could take a peek at this code and give me some direction on why the averages for the remaining 2 courses are not displaying?  The code is being run - per console.

Does anything pop out?

Please let me know.

Welcome !

```
<% if current_student.courses.present? %>

  <h5>Here are your courses:</h5>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td width="150"><h5>Course Name</h5></td>
      <td width="150"><h5>Course Average</h5></td>
      <td width="300"><h5>Course Actions</h5></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <% current_student.courses.select(:course_name, :id).where(student_id: current_student.id).each do |course| %>
      <td width="150"><h6> <%= link_to "#{course.course_name}", student_path(current_student, course) %></h6></td>
      <td width="150"><h6> <%= "#{Assignment.where(course_id: course.id, student_id: current_student.id).average(:assignment_grade)}" %></h6></td>
      <td width="150"><h6> <%= link_to "See assignments for this course." %> </h6></td>
     </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
    </table>

 <% else %>
 <h5>You currently do not have any Courses.</h5>
<% end %>
```

[Pic of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afwm9.png)
[Pic of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATDM6.png)

UPDATE:  Thank you for the feedback, I was able to get some numbers to show, however, the average is for total assignments.  It doesn't seem to limit assignment course id to course id?  Any ideas?

```
      <% current_student.courses.select(:course_name).each do |course| %>
        <tr>
        <td width="150"><h6> <%= link_to "#{course.course_name}", student_path(current_student, course) %></h6></td>
        <td width="150"><h6> <%= "#{Assignment.joins(:course).where(student_id: current_student, course_id: course.id).average(:assignment_grade)}" %></h6></td>
        <td width="150"><h6> <%= "#{Assignment.joins(:course).where(student_id: current_student, course_id: 1).count}" %></h6></td>
        <td width="150"><h6> <%= link_to "See assignments for this course." %> </h6></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
```

Of course, if I hardcode the course id, the average show up, but I need to pull in the course number for each do...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKi4I.png)

Comment: Not strictly related, but you don't need `.where(student_id: current_student.id)`. The whole point of using associations like `current_student.courses` is the foreign keys joining the two records are automatically managed for you.

Comment: What is the value of `assignment_grade` for the remaining two courses? i.e, Science and Technology?

Comment: Your ```<tr>``` should be moved into your ```each``` block

Comment: @meagar - thank for pointing that out!  I removed it.

Comment: @Pavan there's 1 assignment_grade for each class right now (Math is 100 / Science 90 / Technology 100 .  -Iyla Konyukhov - I moved, still doesn't show.

Comment: The alignment of your code is not proper. It should be like this `<% each %> <tr><td></td>..</tr><% end %>`

Comment: Can you do `<%= Assignment.where(course_id: course.id, student_id: current_student.id).count %>` inside the each loop and print the output in the question?

Answer (score 0):

If `Assignment.where(course_id: course.id, student_id: current_student.id)` returns no rows then `average` is `nil`. Nil interpolated as a string gives you empty string.

**UPDATE:**

Here is correct version of your partial from UPDATE:

```
<% current_student.courses.each do |course| %>
  <tr>
    <td width="150"><h6><%= link_to "#{course.course_name}", student_path(current_student.id, course.id) %></h6></td>
    <td width="150"><h6><%= Assignment.where(student_id: current_student.id, course_id: course.id).average(:assignment_grade) %></h6></td>
    <td width="150"><h6><%= link_to "See assignments for this course." %></h6></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm starting to believe this could be the reason :)

Comment: @Ilya Konyukhov - Hi All, I made some edits and put the updated code in original post.  Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Ok, new code - new problems. First, remove ```joins(:course)```. There is no need in it since you don’t use it

Comment: Second, in ```where``` condition there should be ```student_id: current_student.id```

Comment: Last, remove ```select(:course_name)```! Because of this select you fetch only course name. Course id is nil, and that’s the reason your assignments aren’t filtered by course

Comment: @EeeDeeBeeCee all my 3 comments above are about your UPDATE section

Comment: Hi Ilya, it works!  remove that select(:course_name), exposed course id!  Now, need to fix my routes!

Comment: Ok, glad to help